# Django ORM: Annotate the Value of matching object

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I've been using Django's ORM `annotate` before with success for a few times, but I'm having trouble with this especific case.

I want to annotate a new field, called `tag_to_show`, when the value of the field `my_tag` matches a certain regular expression.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
queryset.annotate(tag_to_show=Case(When(my_tag__iregex=pattern,
                                         then=Value("I don't know what to put here")),
                                    output_field=CharField(),
                                    default=Value("Not matched")))
```

I'm just applying a regular expression to the `my_tag` field. If the regex matches the string contained in the `my_tag` field of a certain object, I want to annotate its value in a new field called `tag_to_show`.

Any ideas what to put inside de `Value` parameter?

Comment: What do you want as the value of `tag_to_show`? Is it `True` and `False` depending on if the regex is matched or not?

Comment: I want `tag_to_show` to have the vallue of the matching string. But if its value doesn't match the regex, I want it to have the value "Not matched".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the [`F() expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
queryset.annotate(tag_to_show=Case(
                      When(my_tag__iregex=pattern, then=F('my_tag')),
                      output_field=CharField(), 
                      default=Value("Not matched")))
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much AKS.

Comment: I want to assign the matched value how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

```
queryset.annotate(tag_to_show=Case(When(my_tag__iregex=pattern,
               then='my_tag'),
               output_field=CharField(),
               default=Value("Not matched")))
```